# Derivation of a trigonometric identity

Tags: trigonometry

On Wikipedia (article:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) I came across this trigonometric identity in the infinite sums section [image]

In the article no proof was provided and so I would like to know if anyone here knows a proof of the identity.

Comment: I don't see any trigonometry here and the equation is just the Taylor expansion of RHS valid for $|x|<1$.

Comment: do you know Taylor's theorem ?

Comment: Please [type your formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: In which section of that page of Wikipedia can you see that formula?

Comment: The reason why I labeled it as trigonometric is because in the Wikipedia article a trigonometric identity is derived from this logarithmic identity, but yes, it was a misnomer from my side